# Regularity HJB equation

Tags: regularity-theory-of-pdes, hamilton-jacobi-equation

I am studying a stationary Hamilton-Jacobi-Bellman equation on $\mathbb{R}^N$ of the following type

$$-\Delta u+ H(\nabla u)+ c=f(x)$$

where the Hamiltonian can be assumed to be $H(q)=\frac{1}{\gamma}|q|^\gamma$ (or more in general is sufficiently regular). I am looking for a precise reference for the Holder reguarity of the solution $u$ (we assume that it exists) when $f\in C^{0,\alpha}$.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

in the case of **bounded** domains I can suggest the following reference *Journal of differential equations* vol **245** (2008) pages 2939–2957 . I hope this can help.